# Python, lxml and removing outer tag from using lxml.html.tostring(el)

Tags: python, lxml

I am using the below to get all of the html content of a section to save to a database

```
el = doc.get_element_by_id('productDescription')
lxml.html.tostring(el)
```

The product description has a tag that looks like this:

```
<div id='productDescription'>

     <THE HTML CODE I WANT>

</div>
```

The code works great , gives me all of the html code but how do I remove the outer layer i.e. the `<div id='productDescription'>` and the closing tag `</div>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert each child to string individually:

```
text = el.text
text += ''.join(map(lxml.html.tostring, el.iterchildren()))
```

Or in even more hackish way:

```
el.attrib.clear()
el.tag = '|||'
text = lxml.html.tostring(el)
assert text.startswith('<'+el.tag+'>') and text.endswith('</'+el.tag+'>')
text = text[len('<'+el.tag+'>'):-len('</'+el.tag+'>')]
```

Answer (score 3):

if your `productDescription` `div` div contains mixed text/elements content, e.g.

```
<div id='productDescription'>
  the
  <b> html code </b>
  i want
</div>
```

you can get the content (in string) using `xpath('node()')` traversal:

```
s = ''
for node in el.xpath('node()'):
    if isinstance(node, basestring):
        s += node
    else:
        s += lxml.html.tostring(node, with_tail=False)
```

Comment: What is `basestring`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does what you want.

```
def strip_outer(xml):
    """
    >>> xml = '''<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML         http://www.w3.org/Math/XMLSchema/mathml2/mathml2.xsd">
    ...   <mrow>
    ...     <msup>
    ...       <mi>x</mi>
    ...       <mn>2</mn>
    ...     </msup>
    ...     <mo> + </mo>
    ...     <mi>x</mi>
    ...   </mrow>
    ... </math>'''
    >>> so = strip_outer(xml)
    >>> so.splitlines()[0]=='<mrow>'
    True

    """
    xml = xml.replace('xmlns=','xmlns:x=')#lxml fails with xmlns= attribute
    xml = '<root>\n'+xml+'\n</root>'#...and it can't strip the root element
    rx = lxml.etree.XML(xml)
    lxml.etree.strip_tags(rx,'math')#strip <math with all attributes
    uc=lxml.etree.tounicode(rx)
    uc=u'\n'.join(uc.splitlines()[1:-1])#remove temporary <root> again
    return uc.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp.

```
def strip_outer_tag(html_fragment):
    import re
    outer_tag = re.compile(r'^<[^>]+>(.*?)</[^>]+>$', re.DOTALL)
    return outer_tag.search(html_fragment).group(1)

html_fragment = strip_outer_tag(tostring(el, encoding='unicode'))  # `encoding` is optionaly
```